# Micro switch off in forward and on in backward

Tags: circuit-design, switches, dc-motor, reverse-polarity, dpdt

I have a circuit connected to a DC 12V motor and a DPDT switch to reverse the polarity of the motor and a variable potentiometer. I will need the motor to be stopped temporarily via a microswitch, only in the reverse direction. However, the microswitch must have no effect in the forward. Is this possible using only 1 battery pack? And how would I have to wire the switch into the circuit for this to work?

Comment: What type of microswitch are you using? Normally open (NO) or normally closed (NC)? With an NC this is trivial.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I'm using normally open, meaning the motor will run but when the switch is pressed will shut off motor. Regards

Comment: You must assume we know what you know about this circuit.  Like what kind of motor, make, model?  Why you think a microswitch may affect forward.  Why there is a potentiometer and how it is connected.  Schematic?

Comment: HI Thankyou for the reply, so the dpdt switch will allow the polarity of the motor to be reversed, currently the microswitch is just integrated within the wire from the dpdt motor terminal to the motor, meaning the motor can go forward and backward both being stored when the Normally open microswitch is off, the potentiometer allows me to limit the speed and also is in series, (from dpdt to motor)

Comment: What I require is a method to wire the microswitch using only one battery pack for the microswitch (No) to be effective only in the reverse position but not in the forward position, the dpdt is an on-ON switch, forgive me if I'm not entirely clear I'm new to electrics.

Comment: Also the motor is just a small dc motor using for a small vehicle for a test, regards

Comment: This sounds more like a mechanical problem. If I am reading the question and comments correctly, it sounds like you want the motor to drive up to some location or angle then reverse. But do not want it to do so when it goes past the switch in the other direction. This can be done by arranging the switch lever mechanism properly.

Comment: But perhaps a drawing of your schematic and mechanical idea would give us more of a clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is quite easy.

However, the question of NC/NO needs to be addressed first. I assume that your microswitch is used as a mechanical limit switch. In this case, the "regular" or "normal" operation is with the switch closed, and it opens when the limit is reached. With this in mind this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM4sDr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

shows the way to wire the system without a limit switch. Note that the indicated position of the switch corresponds to forward travel. Activating the lower position produces reverse by reversing the polarity of the motor drive. This

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fplm5L.png)</sup>

uses the limit switch to interrupt current to the motor, but only in the reverse position. SW2, the limit switch, is shown in the NC position. When it opens, reverse drive will be interrupted.

There is one more condition, though. This assumes that the motor is a brushed DC motor. The circuit will not work on stepper motors or BLDCs (brushless DC motor) or AC motors.

Comment: For the second circuit that you drew if switch 2 was to be 'normally open' as a closed circuit ( when pressed the vehicle will stop) would I have to wire them to the negative side of the battery? If that makes sence?

Comment: @Mcccccc - The description makes sense, but the idea doesn't. You must use a normally closed limit switch. If you like, you can connect it to the negative battery lead, but then it must be connected to the 2nd from top lead on the DPDT switch.

Comment: @Mcccccc you need to use a normally closed switch for a limit switch, so the switch can pass current when the motor needs to run and interrupt the current when it needs to stop. there may be a mechanical arrangem,ent where you can make a normally open switch behave normally closed.